# Automated download of whole mysql database without mysqldump

Tags: mysql, ssh

On my shared webhost, I have very limited ssh access (only via imscp instantSSH plugin). I want to set up a script to download my whole mysql database as an sql file, but I cant figure it out.

I cant use mysqldump so I tried the mysql command, which is available, but it isn working.

I have to specify username, password, host and database, and my password contains special characters.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can try pushing Adminer.php (https://www.adminer.org/) file on server and then export the database using Adminer, Adminer is a single PHP file for Mysql GUI

Comment: You need a different hosting platform. That sounds ridiculously restrictive.

Answer (score 2):

If your shared host allow mysql remote connections then you can use any MySQL software to connect to the database and then extract whatever information you need. Tools like these are: HeidiSQL, NavicatGui etc.

Another way would be the one suggested by Akshay Khale.

A 3rd one would be to use phpMyAdmin (most shared web hosting have this installed by default).

A 4th one would to create a simple php script that runs mysqldump locally, saves the .sql dump file either locally on your shared hosting or remotely via FTP/SFTP or any other protocal. Also the same script can email you that file (inline or as an attachment to the email). This kind of automation can be configured using a cron job.

There are multiple ways to achieve this. It all depends on which one suits you best.

Comment: I would not recommend PHPMyAdmin but [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) is a very good option, you can try [PopSQL](https://popsql.io/) also.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Remote connections are not allowed, that would be too easy...ill look into adminer, thats sounds interesting! There is phpmyadmin installed, but I am looking for an automated way that i can trigger from the command line of my local machine during my deploy scripts or something! Probably i really just have to write a small php and trigger it via curl...

Comment: You can make it in php, or bash or whatever is easier for you. Python will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

As the author of the InstantSSH plugin for i-MSCP, I can say you that you should ask your HPs to make the mysqldump command available from your chrooted shell. The host administrator can add any command to the chroot by editing the InstantSSH plugin configuration file.